# \usetikzlibrary should be used only in preamble in case of french babel

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, preamble, french, tikzlibrary

The compilation of the following MWE (**Edit:** The `babel` library is now loaded in the preamble, as needed (thanks to an @egreg's comment), and another one, no matter which one, is loaded after the preamble.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\end{document}
```

fails with the error:

```
Runaway argument?
Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgf@parseid was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

(whatever the `tikz` library used in the document body).

But if either:

- `babel` package with `french` option is not used, or
- `\usetikzlibrary` in the document body is moved in the preamble,

everything works like a charm (the `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` has nothing to do with the problem, it is just recommended when `babel` package is loaded, especially with the `french` option).

What's the reason of this error and how to circumvent it?

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary` should be used in the preamble no matter what.

Comment: I think @egreg means that it should ***only*** be used in the preamble. At least, I hope so. [If I don't have any pictures in a document, I don't even load `tikz`!]

Comment: @egreg Why? That's not mentioned in the `tikz` documentation. The reason of my question is that I have to gather, in a single (main) source file, source (sub)files from several authors, some of them containing `\usetikzlibrary` and I'd prefer to let these commands in the subfiles.

Comment: @cfr That's what I understood :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The project is yours. But surely the `babel` library *must* be in the preamble: after `\begin{document}` it's too late for its fixes to work.

Comment: @egreg The `babel` library is just an example. In my real project, this library is indeed in the preamble and that's other libraries (e.g. the `shapes.misc` one) that I'd like to load after the preamble.

Comment: The point is that whether it is safe to load the libraries later or not will depend entirely on the nature of the code in the library and, possibly, what else is going on in your document. So if you want a general rule, it has to be 'use this only in the preamble'. If you are willing to check the code of each library you wish to use, separating out those which require the preamble from those which do not, that is obviously your choice. I know, for example, that a couple of custom libraries I have would be fine wherever because the code could equally be put in the document body.

Comment: @cfr Why isn't it mentioned in the `tikz` manual that `\usetikzlibrary` should be 'use[d] only in the preamble'?

Comment: Presumably because it depends on the contents of the library. It is just code, after all. Whether that code needs to be loaded in the preamble or not depends on the code. The library loading mechanism is a generic mechanism. What I'm saying is that if you want a *general* rule, it has to be 'use it only in the preamble' because that will work for all libraries. But it is not because of the library loading mechanism itself. It is because some libraries contain code which should only be used in the preamble. [Note: I'm just guessing. Only the author could say for sure.]

Comment: @cfr Hence I guess the problem comes just from `french` `babel`, presumably from its active characters (`?;:!`) that used to conflict with `tikz` and, if I'm right, that's one of the reasons of the `babel` `tikz` library. And my point is that, maybe, any `tikz` library can be used in the document body, and  the fact it is not the case if `french` `babel` is used is an anomaly.

Comment: So the example in your question doesn't produce the error you said it did?

Comment: @cfr Yes, it produces the error I said. I don't see your point.

Comment: Because that example loads `babel` in the preamble. It loads a different library in the document body. Or do you mean that using the `babel` package with the `french` option makes it problematic, regardless of the library concerned? I thought you meant that the `babel` library was problematic if using `french` with the package `babel`, but that other libraries would be OK.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I edited my question with the hope it is less ambiguous now. Yes, the problem comes from the `babel` package with the `french` option (the presence of the `babel`'s `tikz` library is to prevent comments about the possible necessity of it as soon as `babel` package is loaded with the `french` option).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to load code after `babel` has made characters active it is usually best to locally undo that, here it seems to work to turn off `:`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{:}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\shorthandon{:}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be expected to be done by `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`? I mean, with this library, Till Tantau already helped a lot package `babel` users (especially French ones) but maybe the situation I described could be taken in account. Another strange thing is the `/cvsroot/...` absolute path.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I know nothing about tikz and little about babel, so I have very few expectations here sorry. I just answered as I made a guess and it seemed to work. You could always raise it with the tikz maintainers that (even without explicitly flagging babel) it could protect itself against active `:`

Comment: Done [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/353/).